# NVidia backlight control (Again) Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, brightness, 21.04, backlight

Wasn't sure where to post this, so it's in both the forums and also AskUbuntu. Sorry for the cross posting.

Hi,
I've been using Ubuntu for about a year now and have just bought a new laptop.
I installed Ubuntu once again along side Windoze 11 on separate partitions.

Like previously, the combination of i7 and NVidia GPU results in no backlight control.

Confident I could fix the problem like previously I went about searching the web for a solution. Unfortunatily, this time I have been unable to come up with a working solution for this laptop. So I'm reaching out for help.

Configuration:
Dell Alienware X17
Intel i7
NVidia RTX3070
32Gb ram

Things I have tried:

1. Adding acpi_backlight=vendor to the grub command line. Changed it to 'video' and also 'legacy'
2. Adding
   nvidia
   nvidia-drm
   nvidia-modeset
   to /etc/initramfs-tools
3. Added
   Section "Device"
   Identifier "Device0"
   Driver "nvidia"
   VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
   Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
   EndSection
   To /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf
4. The output from
   xrandr | grep " connected" | cut -f1 -d " "
   results in
   XWAYLAND0
   The output of
   xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --brightness 0.7
   results in no change
5. The contents of
   /sys/class/backlight
   intel_backlight
   although I have seen other entries in here.

Any help would be greatfully recieved.

Comment: you missed out the version of ubuntu. please [edit] your question accordingly

Comment: Additional to Test 1 I also tried leaving it blank with ie "quite splash acpi_backlight=" I've also tried it with "quiet splash acpi_backlight=linux"

Comment: Yet another update. I've now done a clean install with Ubuntu 21.1 and tried all the usual methods to get the backlight working. Still nothing works. If anyone know's of tests I can do.... Even to find out the how the light is controlled.

Comment: Interestingly, now, under 21.1, when I use xrandr | grep " connected" | cut -f1 -d " " I get eDP1. Typing xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 0.7, the brightness does actually now change. But is it really changing the brightness or changing the saturation of the display?

Comment: In my attempt to fix this issue I tried various versions of Linux and finally settled on Mint Linux. Out of the box there were no video drivers and many other things didn't work, like wifi and ethernet. I successfully got the backlight and all other hardware functioning by upgrading the kernel. The full solution can be found here.
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=364016&p=2113188#p2113188